# Leibniz rule for partial derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

I have the following integral

$$\int_a^b f(w, t)dt$$

where $w \in \Bbb R^n$ and I need to compute partial derivatives with respect to all components of $w$. How can I apply Leibniz rule to this problem?

Suggested answer:

> $$\int_a^b \frac {\partial f(w, t)} {\partial w_i}dt$$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: This is not the Leibniz rule. It's just plain old differentiation under the integral sign. With appropriate hypotheses, just do the obvious thing.

Comment: @Ted so, I can just put partial derivative under the integral? I edited answer, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right (assuming the partial derivative is, say, continuous).  I would write $\partial$ instead of $\delta$, of course. :)

Comment: @Ted thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use partial derivative under the integral for all needed component of w: $\int_a^b \frac {\partial f(w, t)} {\partial w_i}dt$ . And we don't need Leibniz rule, since the interval is constant